# How to change interval for node status sync

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am using openshift and testing HA features, pods have been running on 2 nodes as the following:

```
$ oc get pods -o wide
NAME            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP             NODE
hello-1-7j6zp   1/1       Running   0          18m       10.128.0.153   node1.exampledis.com

hello-1-mztf8   1/1       Running   0          18m       10.128.0.152   node1.exampledis.com

hello-1-pmz2g   1/1       Running   0          26m       10.130.0.46   node2.exampledis.com
```

I shutdown vm which runs as node2.exampledis.com, after about 1 minute, new pod begins to startup on node1, pod on node2 becomes "unknown", I think there should be some parameter to control the interval, who can share some points on this?

version:

```
oc v3.6.1+008f2d5
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
features: Basic-Auth

Server https://master.exampledis.com:8443
openshift v3.7.9
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62
```

Best regards

Lan

Answer (score 1):

Kubelet `--sync-frequency` parameter controls sync interval, as shown in [kubelet doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubelet/)

> --sync-frequency: Max period between synchronizing running containers and config (default 1m0s)

Comment: Many thanks! I am using openshift, so I edit /etc/origin/node/node-config.yaml on 2 node machines as the following:

kubeletArguments:
  node-labels:
  - router=yes
  - region=infra
  - zone=default
  - sync-frequency=20s

After restart atomic-openshift-node on 2 node machines, it still take about 5 minutes to start new pod on node1 after node2 has been shutdown.

Did I set it correctly?

Comment: It should be at the same level as `node-labels`, and value should be in an array, for example, `sync-frequency: ["20s"]`.